# "The repository is not signed" error when running sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager, repository

Here is the result when I use the command `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu focal InRelease [6353 B]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Err:2 http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6C0DAC728B29D817
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6C0DAC728B29D817
E: The repository 'http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed all the instructions [here](https://openfoam.org/download/9-ubuntu/):

1. Copy and paste the following in a terminal prompt (Applications → Accessories → Terminal) to add dl.openfoam.org to the list of software repositories for apt to search, and to add the public key (gpg.key) for the repository to enable package signatures to be verified.
   Note: use secure https:// for the public key to ensure secure transfer, but usehttp:// for the repository, since https:// may not be supported and is not required since the key provides secure authentication of the package files.

> sudo sh -c "wget -O - https://dl.openfoam.org/gpg.key | apt-key add -"
> sudo add-apt-repository http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu

2. Update the apt package list to account for the new download repository location

> sudo apt-get update

3. Install OpenFOAM (9 in the name refers to version 9) which also installs paraviewopenfoam56 as a dependency.

> sudo apt-get -y install openfoam9

Especially the first step, which adds the GPG key, which you seem to be missing.

Comment: Hello. This is not an answer. If all you offer is go to this link then you have no answer at all. What about later when that link is gone? If any of these links actual are of any value you need to have that info in your answer not just links.

Comment: "no answer at all"